# Redirect http to https just on a specific port flask

Tags: python, http, flask, https

I have a flask application which valids on https. I want to redirect every http request to https. I have this function:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.url.startswith("http://"):
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://' , 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code= code)
```

But it works just when i use port 5000  (Which is flask's default). Otherwise, I get a "connection was reset" error from my browser.

Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: A redirect is a HTTP response. You need to bind a webserver/your program on every port you wish to generate one, so the browser can connect to that. If you try to connect to a port without something listening on it you get the "connection reset/refused" error.

Comment: Generally you'd only bind the default HTTP port "80" though, and don't care (let it run into the browser error) if someone connects to e.g. "http://yourdomain.com:51236"

Comment: Thanks Tobias. I ran it on http port 80 and https port 443. As the client, when i typed the http domain, I got a Redirecting page which said "You should be redirected automatically to e.g https://example.com.(https) if not click the links". Just when i clicked the link, I redirected to the desired page. When I used port 5000 I had to run the app just on https, And it all worked without getting any annoying pages.

Comment: You shouldn't see this "You should be redirected automatically" page if the response has a correct (30X) status-code. What looks weird in your code is that you pass `code= code` (the result of an assignment?) as second argument, not just `code`. Maybe that is the issue. (Or I just don't know that syntax, I know nearly nothing of Python.)

Comment: The syntax is fine, I tried to run it again and it worked fine. But, why in port 5000 it was different? Thanks for your responses!